# unable to truncate a parent table even after disabling a FK constraint in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am unable to truncate from a parent table by only disabling the FK constraint in the referring table . I had to actually drop the constraint in the referring table to be able to truncate the parent table.

I did the above step after first truncating the child table.....so I did follow the right order....do i really need to delete the constraint and then bulk insert the data and then re-create the FK constraint?

Comment: It's here: stackoverflow.com/questions/159038/can-foreign-key-constraints-be-temporarily-disabled-using-t-sql

Comment: well...i just need to disable one FK constraint and not all.

Comment: ALTER TABLE MyTable NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

Comment: @user814064 won't work with TRUNCATE !

Comment: nope...the constraint disable in the referring or child table is not still letting me truncate the data in the parent table. I will use DELETE on the parent table and truncate on the child table and will not have to disable any constraints in the process.

Comment: But you are changing the question.   It starts truncate and then finishes bulk insert.  For bulk insert you can just disable.

Comment: hi Blam - i didnt change the question- the purpose of the whole exercise for me is to do a bulk insert via an SP. and i re-process the  input file for each execution and therefore need to start with an empty table...

Comment: Yes you did change the question.  A bulk insert does require an empty table.  Please fix the question and I will remove the down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna use `TRUNCATE` then yes, dropping and recreating the constraint is the only way.

Confirmation in [doc](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260621%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) (with more explanations)

> You cannot use TRUNCATE TABLE on a table referenced by a FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint; instead, use
>   DELETE statement without a WHERE clause. Because TRUNCATE TABLE is not
>   logged, it cannot activate a trigger.

Comment: to empty all the data from the table using DELETE- do i need to disable the FK constraints first?

Comment: @Code12 did you try it?

Comment: What about copying the child tables, renaming the original tables to something else (e.g. with a 'BAK' or some other suffix), then renaming the empty copies to the original tables' names, and truncate from the parent so that the constraint won't interfere? Then of course drop the copied empty tables and rename the originals.

Comment: @Code12 Yes you can, but delete <> truncate. Old but I would say still pertinent : http://codebetter.com/raymondlewallen/2005/05/09/the-difference-in-truncate-and-delete-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

If the child table is empty (or all of the relevant FK values are set to `NULL`), you should be able to `DELETE` from the parent table without disabling or dropping the constraint.

However you won't be able to use `TRUNCATE` even if you disable the constraint and even if the child table is empty. In this case SQL Server checks at the DDL level that the constraint exists and bails out long before it will ever bother checking the data for constraint violations (so it doesn't matter that the table is empty).

So, just use `DELETE` in your case. Unless you are doing this 50,000 times a day, trying to get this to work with `TRUNCATE` seems to be a lot of trouble for very little gain.